# Selenium WebDriver C#: Split method not working for getting part of a sentence

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver in C#. I need to get the date from sentence "If you submit, the next reminder will be on 03/20/2020." Split method line is showing error.

```
<div id="updateText">If you submit, the next reminder will be on 03/20/2020.</div>
```

I used following code:

```
String outputText = driver.FindElement(By.Id("updateText")).Text;
String date = outputText.Split('on ')[1];
```

Comment: You'd need to do `Split(new[] {"on "}, StringSplitOptions.None)`

Comment: Can you please clarify.                                                                                            
 String date = outputText.Split(new[] {"on "}, String SplitOptions.None)[1];                         Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, I was just showing how to properly use `Split` you'd then need to pull the value from the second index.

Answer (score 0):

Split('on ') is trying to split on a single character. "on " is a string. You need to use "" instead of ''.

Split("on ")

```
String outputText = driver.FindElement(By.Id("updateText")).Text;

// When using a string you have to specify the split option
String result= outputText.Split("on ", System.StringSplitOptions.None);

// You should check it split correctly and also remove the . at the end
var date = result.Count() == 2 ? result[1].Replace('.', ' ').Trim() : "";
```

Comment: I used double quotes, but still showing error.
String date = outputText.Split("on ")[1];

Comment: Is there more than one item in the array? First item in the array would be: 
String date = outputText.Split("on ")[0];

Comment: Its showing error in ("on ") and provide actions like Introduce constant for "on "

Comment: I updated the code in the answer to address your issue. I just double checked it in Visual Studio.

Comment: The `Split` does not have an overload that takes a single string it's `public string[] Split (string[] separator, StringSplitOptions options);` so you have to put the string into an array and pass that in.

Comment: Why the down vote? Here is the Microsoft documentation showing it works. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1 If you are using .NET Framework, then yes, you have to use it in a string array instead as shown in the .NET Framework documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8